# Does the mobiscroll time preset support invalid values?

Tags: mobiscroll

In the date preset, it is possible to make invalid (not selectable) certain days of the week, days of the month, etc., as shown in this example: http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime/date#

Is it possible to do this with the time preset?

Ideally, I'd want to be able to do something like this, for example, which would make the times between 5pm and 9am not selectable:

```
    $('#scroller').mobiscroll({
        preset: 'time',
        display: 'modal',
        invalid: { timesBetween: ['17:00','08:59'] }
    );
```

I do realize it is possible to create a custom set of wheels and only populate them with selections that I want.  However that does not address my needs the same way this would.

Comment: Regarding my specific need: I want to only allow the user to select a time from Now+30 minutes and a fixed time of day (say, 5:30pm).  I could build a custom set of wheels that only includes hours 9am through 6pm, but that leaves 5:31-5:59 as invalid selections the user can make.  Not to mention the dynamic aspect involved in dealing with the current time + 30 minutes.  My only recourse at the current moment is to simply give all the hours and minutes in the day, and just put up an alert when an invalid selection is made.  Not very nice.

Comment: This in on the development list. For more info see: https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll/issues/94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the 2.8 Release, [invalid](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/datetime#opt-invalid) for times got introduced. You can set it for certain days, daysOfWeek, Month, recurring days.

Example:

```
invalid: [
    '1/1', // 1st of January disabled
    '12/24', // Christmas disabled
    '12/25', // Christmas disabled
    'w0', // Sundays disabled
    { start: '00:00', end: '08:00' }, // Every day
    { start: '16:00', end: '23:59' }, // Every day
    { d: 'w6', start: '00:00', end: '08:59' }, // Saturday
    { d: 'w6', start: '17:00', end: '23:59' } // Saturday
]
```